# Processing strings in python according to what's already in the string

Tags: python, string

first of all, id like to say that i am a beginner to python. This beung said i am currently trying to make a program that takes text from a .docx file and edits it to separate each line after a full stop, such as turning "Hello world. Helloworld helloworld. Helloword? Helloworld!" into

"Hello world.
Helloworld helloworld.
Helloword?
Helloworld!"

Ive managed to import the docx document into python, but im still trying to find a way to edit the string to become this way

```
import textract
filename = (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\testdocument.docx')
newtext = textract.process(filename)
```

From here i don't really know how to contiue

Comment: your example of turning A into B contains exactly the same text for A and B, so it's not clear what you want to change.  Do you want to change `". "` to `".\n"`?

Comment: Welcome!  I've not used that library but I'm assuming that you have a 'plain string' after those three lines.  If you could add the result of 'print(new text)' to your question and provide the string you're looking to produce, it'd be more useful.  I'd format it as you have the program text so it's clear what the 'before' and 'after' should be.

Comment: I'm making the same kind of assumption as Sembei above and I suspect you want to look at the string functions (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) where you'll find replace(), which will allow you to make the sort of change that we think you're trying to make.  Remember in python you don't change strings, but create a new copy so it might be: newtext = newtext.replace(". ", ".\n") that you want.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki , yes, i wat to turn the place after the dot into a new line, for some reason it didnt show up in the question

Comment: @Thickycat The docx file i important contains a really long page of sample text sentences, but i can write a simpler version here.

im trying to turn "Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum!" into 

"lorem ipsum. /n
, Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. /n 
Lorem ipsum!" The string is a "plain string" as you said and can just be printed into python. Im going to try the replace thing and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both put a newline after each "." and also neaten trailing spaces and such, you could try:

```
newtext = "Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum!"
after = ".\n".join([line.strip() for line in newtext.split(".")])
```

This works by splitting the original string on ".", then putting it back together while stripping whitespace from either end using a comprehension.

The result is:

```
Lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum!
```

An exploration of those concepts will be very useful in your journey into Python! :)

Comment: I think you should spit using `". "` instead of just `"."`  Otherwise decimal numbers like "1.23" will get split into two lines

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Good point, but also good to be wary that the 'spaces' after the "." might not actually be spaces - Word does some weird things and I don't know how much the extract library sanitises things.

Comment: @Thickycat i tried it, but it doesent work. It extends the length between paragraphs in the word document i added, but it doesent actually add a new line after the end of a sentence. At first it gave me an error about it not being byte-type, but i managed to solve that, and it just gave me the sentences as they were before, but now with extra spaces after the end of a paragraph

Comment: The original question, although obviously taking text from a word document, was asking about modifying a string to put newlines after full stops, which I think the answer does.  However...  Word doesn't split paragraphs on newlines, it holds each paragraph as a separate block with a 'paragraph format' applied to that block so if you want to write the result back to the document, you'll need to look at the documentation to see how to split the paragraphs - it's probably not a case of simply adding linefeeds.  It looks like your library actually just changes them to white space characters.